# In-depth guidance for building complex WinForms Setup projects

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, deployment, setup-project

Where can I find in-depth guidance for building complex WinForms Setup projects?  To be specific, I need to build a single setup package for a DevExpress eXpressApp WinForms application, including a setup for SQL Server 2008 Express, and the creation of a database from scripts.  The DevExpress bit is no problem - the Setup Project Wizard neatly includes all dependencies, but guidance on SQL, running other programs from Setup, etc. seems scant.  Nearly all articles I find overlook anything beyond the same package the wizard creates.

It looks like I have to go collecting little separate bits all over the place to get the whole task done.  I would like to find a single, advanced and comprehensive resource that covers all aspects of WinForms deployment.  Maybe somebody can recommend a book?

*I used to be quite the master at this, even manually editing tables in the .msi files, writing C++ booby-trappers etc. but that was over 10 years ago, and my knowledge seems to have atrophied completely.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several resources:

- Apress Windows Installer http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590592972, but it was published in 2004, so it could be rather out of date;
- c-sharpcorner.com article http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/Setup08232007071849AM/Setup.aspx;
- MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx;

Hope it can help!